# Python: Combine multiple class decorators and get same behaviour in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-decorators, python-dataclasses

For my API types, I require each type to be decorated with three different decorators, some of which take parameters. In order to prevent errors and improve readability I would like to combine these decorators into a single one that I can then make available through a common utility package.

I have managed to combine them using the following code, but PyCharm does not provide proper autocorrect or documentation as if I was using the @dataclass decorator.

What am I missing in order for PyCharm to have the proper metadata?

```
import json
import unittest
from dataclasses import dataclass

from serde import deserialize, serialize
from serde.json import to_dict, to_json


def api_type(cls):
    wrapper = dataclass(cls)
    wrapper = deserialize(wrapper, rename_all='camelcase')
    wrapper = serialize(wrapper, rename_all='camelcase')
    return wrapper


# Test Constants
REQUIRED = "Required value"
OPTIONAL = "Optional value"


# Annotate the test classes
@api_type
class TestApiObjectAPI:
    required_value: str
    optional_value: str


@dataclass
class TestApiObjectDataclass:
    required_value: str
    optional_value: str

TestApiObjectAPI(req)
TestApiObjectDataclass(req)
```

Here is an example of the different behaviour: 
[image: @dataclass decorator: Autocomplete is shown] 
@dataclass decorator: Autocomplete is shown

[image: @api_type decorator : Autocomplete is missing] 
@api_type decorator : Autocomplete is missing

Comment: functools.wraps?

Comment: I've tried `functools.wraps`, `functools.update_wrapper`, `decorator.decorator`, but none of those seem to make a difference.

Edit: Some of those even create more issues when more complex dataclass features such as fields(metadata=...) are used

Comment: ah well, was worth a shot :(  I don't use pycharm, sadly

Comment: I really do like Pycharm, but it has absolutely *crap* support for decorators in general. One reason I avoid decorators in my code whereever possible. In fact this design actually forces you to avoid designing *any* kind of decorators, which is something I don't understand.

Comment: By the way, an easy resolution for this is to use class inheritance instead. Define a base API class which is a dataclass, and put all your fields in there. Autocomplete should work in this case.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Inheritance would not solve the issue as each inheriting class must define its own fields, otherwise there's not really a reason to create it. If the base class is only an empty class using the decorators, the inheriting class is no longer a dataclass which therefore does not solve the problem either.

Comment: hmm, how about a metaclass instead? on occasion, i've needed to use a metaclass instead of a decorator, as pycharm does seem to dislike decorators.

Comment: btw, what does `deserialize(wrapper, rename_all='camelcase')` etc. do?